# Catch classes with specific template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-templates

Is it possible to catch only classes that have a specific template argument, i.e., something like this:

```
template< typename T >
void foo( T<int> )
{
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use a `template template` argument

```
template <template <typename> class T>
void foo( T<int> )
{
  // do something
}
```

You can also write

```
template <typename...> class T
```

to intercept a type `T` that receive zero or more type parameters (example: to intercept `std::vector` that receive two type where the second is with a default value).

Comment: @abraham_hilbert - answer improved; I suggest you to search "template template c++" with google because is an important issue in modern c++; the `typename` (you can also use `class`, but I think `typename` is more clear) inside `< >` say that `T` is a template class with a `typename` argument; by example if you write `template <typename, std::size_t> class A`, you ask for a template class `A` that need a type and a `std::size_t` value as template argument (like `std::array`).